# Qt Translucent background causes child widget to be 'imprinted' in parent

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, translucency

I have a parent container (`MyCartParentWidget`) with translucent background, inside which I have to draw a child widget (`MyCart`) with an image background ([this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I3aG.jpg) is in portrait, [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asBuP.jpg) is in landscape), also drawn with translucent background, and both being `QLabels`. There is a button clicking on which, the child widget toggles its dimensions (`resetCartStyle`), i.e it goes from portrait to landscape mode and vice versa. Problem is, when it toggles, the original imprint stays back, i.e, this is the original pic where it is in 'portrait' mode:

[image]

Then when I switch to 'landscape' mode, it does shift, but the original 'portrait' mode stays back:

[image]

This is my code:

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "MyCartParentWidget.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyCartParentWidget p;
    p.move(370,10);
    p.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

MyCart.cpp:

```
 #include "MyCart.hpp"
 #include <QPainter>

MyCart::MyCart(QWidget *parent): QLabel(parent)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    fPixMap.load("/Users/attitude/Desktop/RnSghvV.png");
    setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0,0,0,255);");
    setFixedSize(325,400);

}

void MyCart::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    p.setRenderHint(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);
    p.drawPixmap(0,0,width(),height(),fPixMap);
}

void MyCart::resetCartStyle(QString url, int w, int h)
{
    setFixedSize(w,h);
    fPixMap.load(url);
    this->update();
}
```

MyCart.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <QLabel>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QPixmap>


class MyCart: public QLabel
{
public:
    MyCart(QWidget*);
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
    QPixmap fPixMap;
    void resetCartStyle(QString, int w, int h);
};
```

MyCartParentWidget.cpp:

```
#include "MyCartParentWidget.hpp"
#include <QPushButton>

MyCartParentWidget::MyCartParentWidget()
{

    setFixedSize(800,700);
    setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    setStyleSheet("background-color: none;");

    fLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    setLayout(fLayout);
    fLayout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
    fLayout->setSpacing(0);
    fLayout->setMargin(0);
    fLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt:: AlignTop);
    i = 0;

    fCart = new MyCart(this);
    fLayout->addWidget(fCart);

    QPushButton* p = new QPushButton(this);
    p->setText("Toggle");
    p->move(0,650);
    connect(p,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(clickedSlot()));
}

void MyCartParentWidget::clickedSlot()
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        //enter landscape mode
        i = 1;
        fCart->resetCartStyle("/Users/attitude/Desktop/foo.png",400,325);
    }
    else
    {
        //enter portrait mode
        i = 0;
        fCart->resetCartStyle("/Users/attitude/Desktop/RnSghvV.png",325,400);
    }
}
```

MyCartParentWidget.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <QLabel>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include "MyCart.hpp"


class MyCartParentWidget: public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyCartParentWidget();

    QHBoxLayout* fLayout;
    MyCart *fCart;
    int i;

private slots:
    void clickedSlot();
};
```

This problem does not happen when I set the background of the parent widget to something like `green` and comment out the `setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);` part, this happens only with `setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);` part.

How do I fix this?

Platform - OS X Yosemite, Qt 5.3.1, 32 bit.

Ilya's solution below works fine on Windows, but the problem persists on Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of painting/updating manually, just call the `setPixmap` method, the `QLabel` should manage itself. The code is working fine, **except on Mac OS X**:

MyCart.cpp:

```
#include "MyCart.hpp"

MyCart::MyCart(QWidget *parent): QLabel(parent)
{
   resetCartStyle("C:/dev/cart/portrait.png");
}

void MyCart::resetCartStyle(QString url)
{
   fPixMap.load(url);
   setPixmap(fPixMap);
}
```

MyCart.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <QLabel>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QPixmap>


class MyCart: public QLabel
{
public:
    MyCart(QWidget*);
    QPixmap fPixMap;
    void resetCartStyle(QString);
};
```

MyCartParentWidget.cpp:

```
#include "MyCartParentWidget.hpp"
#include <QPushButton>

MyCartParentWidget::MyCartParentWidget()
{

    setFixedSize(800,700);
    setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);

    fLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    setLayout(fLayout);
    fLayout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
    fLayout->setSpacing(0);
    fLayout->setMargin(0);
    fLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt:: AlignTop);
    i = 0;

    fCart = new MyCart(this);
    fLayout->addWidget(fCart);

    QPushButton* p = new QPushButton(this);
    p->setText("Toggle");
    p->move(0,650);
    connect(p,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(clickedSlot()));
}

void MyCartParentWidget::clickedSlot()
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        //enter landscape mode
        i = 1;
        fCart->resetCartStyle("C:/dev/cart/landscape.png");
    }
    else
    {
        //enter portrait mode
        i = 0;
        fCart->resetCartStyle("C:/dev/cart/portrait.png");
    }
}
```

So what about Mac OS ? The result is a bit better with Qt 5.5.1 than with 5.3.1,  here's a screenshot (Mac OS 10.11):

[image]

So, there's a ghost of the image remaining. To get to a fully correct display,
the simplest and most effective trick is to hide/show the parent widget before/after toggling:

```
void MyCartParentWidget::clickedSlot()
{
    hide();
    if (i == 0)
    {
        //enter landscape mode
        i = 1;
        fCart->resetCartStyle("C:/dev/cart/landscape.png");
    }
    else
    {
        //enter portrait mode
        i = 0;
        fCart->resetCartStyle("C:/dev/cart/portrait.png");
    }
    show();
}
```

For completeness, below are two other tricks found while searching for a fix, that have fixed the code of the MCV exemple but not the production application.

First trick:

MyCart.cpp

```
MyCart::MyCart(QWidget *parent): QLabel(parent)
{
   // do nothing in the constructor
}
```

MyCartParentWidget.cpp

```
MyCartParentWidget::MyCartParentWidget()
{
    ...previous code    

    // add this line...
    QTimer::singleShot( 0, this, SLOT(onclicked() ); // ...to show the widget
}
```

This code still doesn't work with Qt 5.3.1, the OP's version.
For this Qt version, another fix is necessary (lifted from [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-38760) bug report). NB that fix **doesn't** suppress the ghost image for Qt 5.5.1.

```
void MyCartParentWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter p( this );    
    p.setCompositionMode( QPainter::CompositionMode_Clear );
    p.fillRect( this->rect(), Qt::transparent );
}
```

So for a working code (for the exemple) on Mac OS with both Qt versions (5.3.1 and 5.5.1), you have to use both tricks.

Comment: For instance `QPainter::fillRect`

Comment: Yes, `fillRect` with what? Please provide a minimal working example.. I assume you are talking about overriding the `paintEvent` of `MyCartParentWidget`?

Comment: Something like `fillRect( rect(), QColor(0, 0, 0, 0) );`

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. I added `paintEvent` method in `MyCartParentWidget`, where all I am doing is `QPainter p(this);  p.fillRect( rect(), QColor(0, 0, 0, 0) );`. And in the `resetCartStyle` method, after calling `this->update();`, I called `this->parentWidget()->update();`. Same result.

Comment: It's not for the parent paint event, it's for the cart paint event, before drawing the pixmap.

Comment: Yes, I put it there as well, for checking it out. See edited question. Same result... Can you give a minimal working example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100945/discussion-between-ilya-and-attitudemonger).

Comment: @AttitudeMonger the result with Q 5.5.1 on Mac OS 10.11 is funny, it's *almost* right...

Comment: I am a bit confused by the edits.. Can you do one final badass edit to your answer and provide the final complete code?

Comment: I've added the full code for the 2 changed files, but I'll probably try to find a cleaner trick for a "final" version. I would also be nice if a Qt guru could explain what's happening behind the scene (Qt bug ?).

Comment: So the timer needs to be called only once, in the constructor of the parent  widget?

Comment: Yes that's it, just a deferred  call.

Comment: Sigh. May be it works in Qt 5.5, in 5.3 it is still the same result.. :(

Comment: Dang. I'll have a look at the Qt bug reports, see if there's something related fixed between 5.3.1 and 5.5.1.

Comment: There's this one: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-38760. Quite similar to your problem, no reference to a fix, but having a workaround.

Comment: Hmmph. This `paintEvent` should be set in the parent widget, or the cart? Parent, right?

Comment: Makes sense to set it in the parent, yes.

Comment: Works like a charm! That's freakishly awesome! I Googled it, but somehow the bugreport did not show up, otherwise it would have been so easy.. :) Anyway, you have more than earned the bounty!

Comment: Well, that was an interesting chase. I'll update the answer with all the infos. Thanks for the bounty BTW.

Comment: Yep, please do... SO is more Googleable than Qt bugreport site.. :(

Comment: Sigh. The ghost image is causing problems..Let's continue in chat.

Comment: @AttitudeMonger does the (production) cart widget contains anything other than the image (a label or a border) ?

Comment: No, it does not contain anything else. The parent widget, followed by the child widget (cart), inside which the OpenGL generated image sits inside a QFrame.

Comment: So in production code the cart is a QFrame and not a QLabel ?

Comment: No no, cart is still a QLabel. Inside it, in the viewport area, there is a QFrame (same size as the viewport) inside which the generated image sits. That image is a QWidget.

Comment: I managed to find a way to make it work, if I hide and show the parent widget after the change, it now repaints correctly, removing the ghost image.

Comment: Great! I remember testing hide/show at some point, but it was probably on the cart and not the parent.

Comment: @AttitudeMonger I've updated the answer with your final (hopefully) solution. What's still missing is an explanation (or real fix) for the Mac OS behavior, from someone able to analyse that part of the Qt code.

Comment: This will never leave me in peace. I have another situation elsewhere, where hiding and showing is not acceptable, so this is hurting me. I described it in detail here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50728. Best of luck!

Comment: Would it help if I reproduce the problem using the bug report code with 5.5 ? I believe that's why the bug report is in a "Need more info" status.

Comment: Yeah sure, feel free! If you say it is the same I might as change the version info there to get more attention, or you may chime in with a comment stating the same..

Comment: Holy smoke, I am back to my home now, even I can try with 5.5! But you do it first and let me know, then I will do..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102085/discussion-between-ilya-and-attitudemonger).